# The specified member 'Date; is not supported in LINQ even after adding "DbFunctions.TruncateTime"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

As mentioned in title, I still got the **"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"** error even after using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, to fetch all the records for current date. I am using `EF 6.1.3` and below is my code on fetching the records. I just want the count of records for today but had no luck to get the same. Below is my code.

```
var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
model.todayVisitors=db.tblVisitors.Where(v => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(v.vDate.Value.Date) 
                    == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(currentDate)).Count();
```

`vDate` in database is of type `datetime2(7)`. Any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't use `.Date`.

Just call `TruncateTime()` *instead of* `.Date` and you'll be fine.

Comment: So something like `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(v.vDate)`?

Comment: Gotcha @SLaks.. Thanks a ton.. :)